# Puxar informação de outra página

Tags: php, libcurl, youtube-api, file-get-contents

Através de uma determinada url recebo o seguinte código

```
    <script>
    window["ytInitialData"] = 
    {"responseContext":{"serviceTrackingParams":
    [{"service":"GFEEDBACK","params":
    [{"key":"has_unlimited_entitlement","value":"False"},
    {"key":"has_unlimited_ncc_free_trial","value":"False"},
    {"key":"e","value":"23700271,23700612,23700927,23.701018,23702322,\n\
    23702700,23702730,23703924,2.3704248,23705485,23705739,23706129,23706541,\n\
    23707489,23708886,23708904,23708906,23708910,23709366,23709525,23709713,\n\
    23709988,23710969,23711501,23712273,3300105,3300130,3300161,3313274,\n\
    3313321,3313362,3314014,3314088,9422596,9431754,9449243,9460517,9464484,\n\
    9471658,9475693,9476327,9477045,9477113,9477759,9480475,9483235,9484237,\n\
    9485000,9487591,9488038,9488572,9489759,9489766"},{"key":"logged_in","value":"1"},
    {"key":"pn","value":"watch"}]},
    {"service":"GUIDED_HELP","params":[{"key":"context","value":"yt_web_kevlar_watch"},
    {"key":"creator_channel_id","value":"UC1OCsz4qA7K6E2QJfbRsWEw"},
    {"key":"logged_in","value":"1"}]},{"service":"CSI","params":
    [{"key":"GetWatchNext_rid","value":"0xa8683074bd527bde"},{"key":"c","value":"WEB"},
    {"key":"cver","value":"2.20171108"},
    {"key":"yt_li","value":"1"}]},
    {"service":"ECATCHER","params":
    [{"key":"client.name","value":"WEB"},
    {"key":"client.version","value":"2.20171108"},
    {"key":"innertube.build.changelist","value":"175185942"},   
    {"key":"innertube.build.experiments.source_version "value":"175356060"},  
    {"key":"innertube.build.label","value":"youtube_20171108_0_RC4"},   
    {"key":"innertube.build.timestamp","value":"1510255866"},   
    {"key":"innertube.build.variants.checksum","value":"c.    38b8ae7b1e57a677202e9b65f9a6f86"},
    {"key":"innertube.run.job","value":"ytfe-jserv-replica-only.ytfe"}]}],
    "webResponseContextExtensionData":{"ytConfigData":{"csn":"1UQIWrqPKcbiwQSa7aXoCQ",
    "visitorData":"CgtnMEdabnNmMjlWOA%3D%3D","sessionIndex":0,"delegatedSessionId":"112905089396363160576",
    "rootVisualElementType":3832},"feedbackDialog":{"polymerOptOutFeedbackDialogRenderer":
    {"title":{"runs":[{"text":"Lamentamos seu cancelamento."}]},"subtitle":{"runs":[
    {"text":"Diga o motivo. Seu feedback ajuda a melhorar o YouTube. Para voltar ao design novo, basta acessar "},
    {"text":"youtube.com/new","navigationEndpoint":{"urlEndpoint":{"url":"https://www.youtube.com/new"},
    "webNavigationEndpointData":{"url":"https://www.youtube.com/new"}}},
    {"text":" a qualquer momento."}]},"options":[{"polymerOptOutFeedbackOptionRenderer":
    {"optionKey":"missing","description":{"runs":[{"text":"Faltam alguns recursos"}]},
    "responsePlaceholder":{"runs":[{"text":"Forneça mais informações"}]}}},
    {"polymerOptOutFeedbackOptionRenderer":{"optionKey":"broken","description":{"runs":[
    [{"text":"Alguns recursos estão corrompidos"}]},"responsePlaceholder":{"runs":
    [{"text":"Forneça mais informações"}]}}},{"polymerOptOutFeedbackOptionRenderer":
    {"optionKey":"harder","description":{"runs":[{"text":"Alguns recursos são difíceis de usar"}]},
    "responsePlaceholder":{"runs":[{"text":"Forneça mais informações"}]}}},
    {"polymerOptOutFeedbackOptionRenderer":{"optionKey":"dislike","description":{"runs":
    [{"text":"Não gosto do novo design"}]},"responsePlaceholder":{"runs":[{"text":"Forneça mais informações"}]}}},
    {"polymerOptOutFeedbackOptionRenderer":{"optionKey":"unlisted","description":{"runs":
    [{"text":"Meu motivo não está listado"}]},"responsePlaceholder":{"runs":[{"text":"Forneça mais informações"}]}}},
    {"polymerOptOutFeedbackNullOptionRenderer":{"description":{"runs":[{"text":"Prefiro não responder"}]}}}],
    "disclaimer":{"runs":[{"text":"Acesse a página de "},{"text":"Ajuda Legal","navigationEndpoint":{"urlEndpoint":
    {"url":"https://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?answer=140536"},"webNavigationEndpointData":
    {"url":"https://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?answer=140536"}}},
    {"text":" para solicitar alterações de conteúdo por razões judiciais. Seu feedback, seu e-mail e outras informações serão enviados para o Google. Consulte a "},
    {"text":"política de privacidade","navigationEndpoint":{"urlEndpoint":{"url":"https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/"}
    ,"webNavigationEndpointData":{"url":"https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/"}}},
    {"text":" e os "},{"text":"Termos de Serviço","navigationEndpoint":{"urlEndpoint":
    {"url":"https://www.google.com/policies/terms/"},"webNavigationEndpointData":
    {"url":"https://www.google.com/policies/terms/"}}},{"text":"."}]},"dismissButton":{"buttonRenderer":
    {"style":"STYLE_TEXT","size":"SIZE_DEFAULT","isDisabled":false,"text":{"runs":[{"text":"Não, obrigado"}]}}},
    "submitButton":{"buttonRenderer":{"style":"STYLE_BRAND","size":"SIZE_DEFAULT","isDisabled":true,"text":{"runs":[{"text":"Enviar"}]}}},"closeButton":{"buttonRenderer":
    {"style":"STYLE_DEFAULT","size":"SIZE_DEFAULT","isDisabled":false,"icon":{"iconType":"CLOSE"}}},"cancelButton":{"buttonRenderer":{"style":"STYLE_TEXT","size":"SIZE_DEFAULT",
    "isDisabled":false,"text":{"runs":[{"text":"Cancelar"}]}}}}}}},"contents":{"twoColumnWatchNextResults":{"results":{"results":{"contents":[{"videoPrimaryInfoRenderer":{"title":{"simpleText":"Gusttavo Lima - Thiago Brava e Amigos (Transmissão ao vivo pelo Facebook) 13/01/2017"},"viewCount":{"videoViewCountRenderer":{"viewCount":{"simpleText":"40.470 visualizações"},"shortViewCount":{"simpleText":"40 mil visualizações"}}},"videoActions":{"menuRenderer":{"items":
    [{"menuServiceItemRenderer":{"text":{"runs":[{"text":"Denunciar"}]},"icon":{"iconType":"FLAG"},"serviceEndpoint":{"clickTrackingParams":"CHwQzKsBGAAiEwj6zdXiirnXAhVGcZAKHZp2CZ0o-B0=","getReportFormEndpoint":{"params":"EgtteXVXR21FNm9CSUABWAA%3D"}},"trackingParams":"CHwQzKsBGAAiEwj6zdXiirnXAhVGcZAKHZp2CZ0o-B0="}},{"menuNavigationItemRenderer":
    {"text":{"runs":[{"text":"Adicionar traduções"}]},"navigationEndpoint":{"clickTrackingParams":"CHwQzKsBGAAiEwj6zdXiirnXAhVGcZAKHZp2CZ0o-B0=","urlEndpoint":{"url":"/timedtext_video?bl=watch\u0026v=myuWGmE6oBI\u0026ref=wt\u0026auto=yes"},
    "webNavigationEndpointData":{"url":"/timedtext_video?bl=watch\u0026v=myuWGmE6oBI\u0026ref=wt\u0026auto=yes"}},"trackingParams":"CHwQzKsBGAAiEwj6zdXiirnXAhVGcZAKHZp2CZ0o-B0="}}],"trackingParams":"CHwQzKsBGAAiEwj6zdXiirnXAhVGcZAKHZp2CZ0o-B0=","topLevelButtons":[{"toggleButtonRenderer":{"style":{"styleType":"STYLE_TEXT"},"isToggled":false,"isDisabled":false,"defaultIcon":{"iconType":"LIKE"},"defaultText":{"accessibility":{"accessibilityData":{"label":"512 pessoas gostaram"}},"simpleText":"512"},"defaultServiceEndpoint":{"clickTrackingParams":"CJABEJhNGAIiEwj6zdXiirnXAhVGcZAKHZp2CZ0o-B0=","likeEndpoint":{"status":"LIKE","target":{"videoId":"myuWGmE6oBI"}}},"toggledText":{"accessibility":{"accessibilityData":{"label":"513 pessoas gostaram"}},"simpleText":"513"},"toggledServiceEndpoint":{"clickTrackingParams":"CJABEJhNGAIiEwj6zdXiirnXAhVGcZAKHZp2CZ0o-B0=","likeEndpoint":{"status":"INDIFFERENT","target":{"videoId":"myuWGmE6oBI"}}},"accessibility":{"label":"Marque este vídeo como \"Gostei\" com mais 512 pessoas"},"trackingParams":"CJABEJhNGAIiEwj6zdXiirnXAhVGcZAKHZp2CZ0o-B0=","defaultTooltip":"Marcar como \"Gostei\"","toggledTooltip":"Anular gostar","toggledStyle":{"styleType":"STYLE_DEFAULT_ACTIVE"},"accessibilityData":{"accessibilityData":{"label":"Marque este vídeo como \"Gostei\" com mais 512 pessoas"}},"toggleButtonSupportedData":
    {"toggleButtonIdData":{"id":"TOGGLE_BUTTON_ID_TYPE_LIKE"}}}},{"toggleButtonRenderer":{"style":{"styleType":"STYLE_TEXT"},"isToggled":false,"isDisabled":false,"defaultIcon":{"iconType":"DISLIKE"},"defaultText":{"accessibility":{"accessibilityData":{"label":"23 marcações \"Não gostei\""}},"simpleText":"23"},"defaultServiceEndpoint":{"clickTrackingParams":"CI8BEJhNGAMiEwj6zdXiirnXAhVGcZAKHZp2CZ0o-B0=","likeEndpoint":{"status":"DISLIKE","target":{"videoId":"myuWGmE6oBI"}}},"toggledText":{"accessibility":{"accessibilityData":{"label":"24 marcações \"Não gostei\""}},"simpleText":"24"},"toggledServiceEndpoint":{"clickTrackingParams":"CI8BEJhNGAMiEwj6zdXiirnXAhVGcZAKHZp2CZ0o-B0=","likeEndpoint":{"status":"INDIFFERENT","target":{"videoId":"myuWGmE6oBI"}}},"accessibility":{"label":"Marque este vídeo como \"Não gostei\" com mais 23 pessoas"},"trackingParams":"CI8BEJhNGAMiEwj6zdXiirnXAhVGcZAKHZp2CZ0o-B0=","defaultTooltip":"Marcar como \"Não gostei\"","toggledTooltip":"Marcar como \"Não gostei\"","toggledStyle":{"styleType":"STYLE_DEFAULT_ACTIVE"},"accessibilityData":{"accessibilityData":{"label":"Marque este vídeo como \"Não gostei\" com mais 23 pessoas"}},"toggleButtonSupportedData":{"toggleButtonIdData":{"id":"TOGGLE_BUTTON_ID_TYPE_DISLIKE"}}}},{"buttonRenderer":{"style":"STYLE_DEFAULT","size":"SIZE_DEFAULT","isDisabled":false,"text":{"runs":[{"text":"Compartilhar"}]},"icon":{"iconType":"SHARE"},"navigationEndpoint":{"clickTrackingParams":"CH4Q8FsYBCITCPrN1eKKudcCFUZxkAodmnYJnSj4HQ==",
    "shareEndpoint":{"serializedShareEntity":"CgtteXVXR21FNm9CSQ%3D%3D","sharingRenderer":{"sharingRenderer":{"openShareMenuAfterWatch":true,"shortUrl":"https://youtu.be/myuWGmE6oBI","primaryShareTargets":[{"shareTargetRenderer":{"targetId":10,"title":{"simpleText":"Facebook"},"navigationEndpoint":{"clickTrackingParams":"CI4BEKpMGAAiEwj6zdXiirnXAhVGcZAKHZp2CZ0o-B1IksDqiabD5ZWbAWoIRkFDRUJPT0s=","urlEndpoint":{"url":"http://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=87741124305\u0026href=https%3A//www.youtube.com/attribution_link%3Fa%3Dqv1tKqc04ZQ%26u%3D%252Fwatch%253Fv%253DmyuWGmE6oBI%2526feature%253Dshare\u0026display=popup\u0026redirect_uri=https://www.youtube.com/facebook_redirect","target":"TARGET_NEW_WINDOW"},"webNavigationEndpointData":{"url":"http://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=87741124305\u0026href=https%3A//www.youtube.com/attribution_link%3Fa%3Dqv1tKqc04ZQ%26u%3D%252Fwatch%253Fv%253DmyuWGmE6oBI%2526feature%253Dshare\u0026display=popup\u0026redirect_uri=https://www.youtube.com/facebook_redirect"}},"trackingParams":"CI4BEKpMGAAiEwj6zdXiirnXAhVGcZAKHZp2CZ0o-B0yBXNoYXJlOgtxdjF0S3FjMDRaUUiSwOqJpsPllZsBaghGQUNFQk9PS3FAddTgFCHqfngB","serviceName":"FACEBOOK"}},{"shareTargetRenderer":{"targetId":8,"title":{"simpleText":"goo"},"navigationEndpoint":{"clickTrackingParams":"CI0BEKpMGAEiEwj6zdXiirnXAhVGcZAKHZp2CZ0o-B1IksDqiabD5ZWbAWoDR09P","urlEndpoint":{"url":"http://blog.goo.ne.jp/portal_login/blogparts/?key=myuWGmE6oBI\u0026title=Gusttavo%20Lima%20-%20Thiago%20Brava%20e%20Amigos%20%28Transmiss%C3%A3o%20ao%20vivo%20pelo%20Facebook%29%2013/01/2017\u0026type=youtube",
    "target":"TARGET_NEW_WINDOW"},"webNavigationEndpointData":{"url":"http://blog.goo.ne.jp/portal_login/blogparts/?key=myuWGmE6oBI\u0026title=Gusttavo%20Lima%20-%20Thiago%20Brava%20e%20Amigos%20%28Transmiss%C3%A3o%20ao%20vivo%20pelo%20Facebook%29%2013/01/2017\u0026type=youtube"}},"trackingParams":"CI0BEKpMGAEiEwj6zdXiirnXAhVGcZAKHZp2CZ0o-B0yBXNoYXJlSJLA6ommw-WVmwFqA0dPT3gB","serviceName":"GOO"}},{"shareTargetRenderer":{"targetId":28,"title":{"simpleText":"hi5"},"navigationEndpoint":{"clickTrackingParams":"CIwBEKpMGAIiEwj6zdXiirnXAhVGcZAKHZp2CZ0o-B1IksDqiabD5ZWbAWoDSEk1","urlEndpoint":{"url":"http://www.hi5.com/friend/checkViewedVideo.do?t=Gusttavo%20Lima%20-%20Thiago%20Brava%20e%20Amigos%20%28Transmiss%C3%A3o%20ao%20vivo%20pelo%20Facebook...\u0026url=https%3A//www.youtube.com/attribution_link%3Fa%3Ds75qnF8ABqs%26u%3D%252Fwatch%253Fv%253DmyuWGmE6oBI%2526feature%253Dshare\u0026embeddable=true\u0026simple=true","target":"TARGET_NEW_WINDOW"},"webNavigationEndpointData":{"url":"http://www.hi5.com/friend/checkViewedVideo.do?t=Gusttavo%20Lima%20-%20Thiago%20Brava%20e%20Amigos%20%28Transmiss%C3%A3o%20ao%20vivo%20pelo%20Facebook...\u0026url=https%3A//www.youtube.com/attribution_link%3Fa%3Ds75qnF8ABqs%26u%3D%252Fwatch%253Fv%253DmyuWGmE6oBI%2526feature%253Dshare\u0026embeddable=true\u0026simple=true"}},"trackingParams":"CIwBEKpMGAIiEwj6zdXiirnXAhVGcZAKHZp2CZ0o-B0yBXNoYXJlOgtzNzVxbkY4QUJxc0iSwOqJpsPllZsBagNISTVxQHXU4BQh6n54AQ==","serviceName":"HI5"}},{"shareTargetRenderer":{"targetId":43,"title":{"simpleText":"Google+"},"navigationEndpoint":{"clickTrackingParams":"CIsBEKpMGAMiEwj6zdXiirnXAhVGcZAKHZp2CZ0o-B1IksDqiabD5ZWbAWoKR09PR0xFUExVUw==","urlEndpoint":{"url":"https://plus.google.com/share?url=https%3A//www.youtube.com/attribution_link%3Fa%3Dg0FcgQaNPpo%26u%3D%252Fwatch%253Fv%253DmyuWGmE6oBI%2526feature%253Dshare\u0026source=yt\u0026hl=pt\u0026soc-platform=1\u0026soc-app=130","target":"TARGET_NEW_WINDOW"},"webNavigationEndpointData":{"url":"https://plus.google.com/share?url=https%3A//www.youtube.com/attribution_link%3Fa%3Dg0FcgQaNPpo%26u%3D%252Fwatch%253Fv%253DmyuWGmE6oBI%2526feature%253Dshare\u0026source=yt\u0026hl=pt\u0026soc-platform=1\u0026soc-app=130"}},"trackingParams":"CIsBEKpMGAMiEwj6zdXiirnXAhVGcZAKHZp2CZ0o-B0yBXNoYXJlOgtnMEZjZ1FhTlBwb0iSwOqJpsPllZsBagpHT09HTEVQTFVTcUB11OAUIep-eAE=","serviceName":"GOOGLEPLUS"}}],"secondaryShareTargets":[{"shareTargetRenderer":{"targetId":31,"title":{"simpleText":"Twitter"},"navigationEndpoint":{"clickTrackingParams":"CIoBEKpMGAQiEwj6zdXiirnXAhVGcZAKHZp2CZ0o-B1IksDqiabD5ZWbAWoHVFdJVFRFUg==","urlEndpoint":{"url":"http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=https%3A//youtu.be/myuWGmE6oBI\u0026text=Gusttavo%20Lima%20-%20Thiago%20Brava%20e%20Amigos%20%28Transmiss%C3%A3o%20ao%20vivo%20pelo%20Facebook...\u0026via=YouTube\u0026related=YouTube,YouTubeTrends,YTCreators","target":"TARGET_NEW_WINDOW"},"webNavigationEndpointData":{"url":"http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=https%3A//youtu.be/myuWGmE6oBI\u0026text=Gusttavo%20Lima%20-%20Thiago%20Brava%20e%20Amigos%20%28Transmiss%C3%A3o%20ao%20vivo%20pelo%20Facebook...\u0026via=YouTube\u0026related=YouTube,YouTubeTrends,YTCreators"}},"trackingParams":"CIoBEKpMGAQiEwj6zdXiirnXAhVGcZAKHZp2CZ0o-B0yBXNoYXJlSJLA6ommw-WVmwFqB1RXSVRURVJ4AQ==","serviceName":"TWITTER"}},{"shareTargetRenderer":{"targetId":34,"title":{"simpleText":"Blogger"},"navigationEndpoint":{"clickTrackingParams":"CIkBEKpMGAUiEwj6zdXiirnXAhVGcZAKHZp2CZ0o-B1IksDqiabD5ZWbAWoHQkxPR0dFUg==","urlEndpoint":{"url":"http://www.blogger.com/blog-this.g?n=Gusttavo%20Lima%20-%20Thiago%20Brava%20e%20Amigos%20%28Transmiss%C3%A3o%20ao%20vivo%20pelo%20Facebook...\u0026source=youtube\u0026b=%3Ciframe%20width%3D%22459%22%20height%3D%22344%22%20src%3D%22https%3A//www.youtube.com/embed/myuWGmE6oBI%22%20frameborder%3D%220%22%20gesture%3D%22media%22%20allowfullscreen%3E%3C/iframe%3E\u0026eurl=https%3A//i.ytimg.com/vi/myuWGmE6oBI/hqdefault.jpg","target":"TARGET_NEW_WINDOW"},"webNavigationEndpointData":{"url":"http://www.blogger.com/blog-this.g?n=Gusttavo%20Lima%20-%20Thiago%20Brava%20e%20Amigos%20%28Transmiss%C3%A3o%20ao%20vivo%20pelo%20Facebook...\u0026source=youtube\u0026b=%3Ciframe%20width%3D%22459%22%20height%3D%22344%22%20src%3D%22https%3A//www.youtube.com/embed/myuWGmE6oBI%22%20frameborder%3D%220%22%20gesture%3D%22media%22%20allowfullscreen%3E%3C/iframe%3E\u0026eurl=https%3A//i.ytimg.com/vi/myuWGmE6oBI/hqdefault.jpg"}},"trackingParams":"CIkBEKpMGAUiEwj6zdXiirnXAhVGcZAKHZp2CZ0o-B0yBXNoYXJlOgtLQlZ6dUdMNDc0QUiSwOqJpsPllZsBagdCTE9HR0VScUB11OAUIep-eAE=","serviceName":"BLOGGER"}},{"shareTargetRenderer":{"targetId":40,"title":{"simpleText":"Tumblr"},"navigationEndpoint":{"clickTrackingParams":"CIgBEKpMGAYiEwj6zdXiirnXAhVGcZAKHZp2CZ0o-B1IksDqiabD5ZWbAWoGVFVNQkxS","urlEndpoint":{"url":"http://www.tumblr.com/share/video?embed=https%3A//www.youtube.com/attribution_link%3Fa%3DNvc1hmOF2q0%26u%3D%252Fwatch%253Fv%253DmyuWGmE6oBI%2526feature%253Dshare\u0026caption=Gusttavo%20Lima%20-%20Thiago%20Brava%20e%20Amigos%20%28Transmiss%C3%A3o%20ao%20vivo%20pelo%20Facebook...","target":"TARGET_NEW_WINDOW"},"webNavigationEndpointData":{"url":"http://www.tumblr.com/share/video?embed=https%3A//www.youtube.com/attribution_link%3Fa%3DNvc1hmOF2q0%26u%3D%252Fwatch%253Fv%253DmyuWGmE6oBI%2526feature%253Dshare\u0026caption=Gusttavo%20Lima%20-%20Thiago%20Brava%20e%20Amigos%20%28Transmiss%C3%A3o%20ao%20vivo%20pelo%20Facebook..."}},"trackingParams":"CIgBEKpMGAYiEwj6zdXiirnXAhVGcZAKHZp2CZ0o-B0yBXNoYXJlOgtOdmMxaG1PRjJxMEiSwOqJpsPllZsBagZUVU1CTFJxQHXU4BQh6n54AQ==","serviceName":"TUMBLR"}},{"shareTargetRenderer":{"targetId":4,"title":{"simpleText":"reddit"},"navigationEndpoint":{"clickTrackingParams":"CIcBEKpMGAciEwj6zdXiirnXAhVGcZAKHZp2CZ0o-B1IksDqiabD5ZWbAWoGUkVERElU","urlEndpoint":{"url":"http://reddit.com/submit?url=https%3A//www.youtube.com/attribution_link%3Fa%3DDeag0_iRT5U%26u%3D%252Fwatch%253Fv%253DmyuWGmE6oBI%2526feature%253Dshare\u0026title=Gusttavo%20Lima%20-%20Thiago%20Brava%20e%20Amigos%20%28Transmiss%C3%A3o%20ao%20vivo%20pelo%20Facebook...","target":"TARGET_NEW_WINDOW"},"webNavigationEndpointData":{"url":"http://reddit.com/submit?url=https%3A//www.youtube.com/attribution_link%3Fa%3DDeag0_iRT5U%26u%3D%252Fwatch%253Fv%253DmyuWGmE6oBI%2526feature%253Dshare\u0026title=Gusttavo%20Lima%20-%20Thiago%20Brava%20e%20Amigos%20%28Transmiss%C3%A3o%20ao%20vivo%20pelo%20Facebook..."}},"trackingParams":"CIcBEKpMGAciEwj6zdXiirnXAhVGcZAKHZp2CZ0o-B0yBXNoYXJlOgtEZWFnMF9pUlQ1VUiSwOqJpsPllZsBagZSRURESVRxQHXU4BQh6n54AQ==","serviceName":"REDDIT"}},{"shareTargetRenderer":{"targetId":42,"title":{"simpleText":"LinkedIn"},"navigationEndpoint":{"clickTrackingParams":"CIYBEKpMGAgiEwj6zdXiirnXAhVGcZAKHZp2CZ0o-B1IksDqiabD5ZWbAWoITElOS0VESU4=","urlEndpoint":{"url":"http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?url=https%3A//www.youtube.com/attribution_link%3Fa%3Dux6WJdhTC50%26u%3D%252Fwatch%253Fv%253DmyuWGmE6oBI%2526feature%253Dshare\u0026title=Gusttavo%20Lima%20-%20Thiago%20Brava%20e%20Amigos%20%28Transmiss%C3%A3o%20ao%20vivo%20pelo%20Facebook...\u0026summary=Transmiss%C3%A3o%20ao%20vivo%20de%20%20Gusttavo%20Lima%20-%20Thiago%20Brava%20e%20Amigos%20%28Transmiss%C3%A3o%20ao%20vivo%20pelo%20Facebook%29%2013/01/2017\u0026source=Youtube","target":"TARGET_NEW_WINDOW"},"webNavigationEndpointData":{"url":"http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?url=https%3A//www.youtube.com/attribution_link%3Fa%3Dux6WJdhTC50%26u%3D%252Fwatch%253Fv%253DmyuWGmE6oBI%2526feature%253Dshare\u0026title=Gusttavo%20Lima%20-%20Thiago%20Brava%20e%20Amigos%20%28Transmiss%C3%A3o%20ao%20vivo%20pelo%20Facebook...\u0026summary=Transmiss%C3%A3o%20ao%20vivo%20de%20%20Gusttavo%20Lima%20-%20Thiago%20Brava%20e%20Amigos%20%28Transmiss%C3%A3o%20ao%20vivo%20pelo%20Facebook%29%2013/01/2017\u0026source=Youtube"}},"trackingParams":"CIYBEKpMGAgiEwj6zdXiirnXAhVGcZAKHZp2CZ0o-B0yBXNoYXJlOgt1eDZXSmRoVEM1MEiSwOqJpsPllZsBaghMSU5LRURJTnFAddTgFCHqfngB","serviceName":"LINKEDIN"}},{"shareTargetRenderer":{"targetId":45,"title":{"simpleText":"Pinterest"},"navigationEndpoint":{"clickTrackingParams":"CIUBEKpMGAkiEwj6zdXiirnXAhVGcZAKHZp2CZ0o-B1IksDqiabD5ZWbAWoJUElOVEVSRVNU","urlEndpoint":{"url":"http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=https%3A//www.youtube.com/attribution_link%3Fa%3DEJTr_gotwJY%26u%3D%252Fwatch%253Fv%253DmyuWGmE6oBI%2526feature%253Dshare\u0026description=Gusttavo%20Lima%20-%20Thiago%20Brava%20e%20Amigos%20%28Transmiss%C3%A3o%20ao%20vivo%20pelo%20Facebook...\u0026is_video=true\u0026media=https%3A//i.ytimg.com/vi/myuWGmE6oBI/hqdefault.jpg","target":"TARGET_NEW_WINDOW"},"webNavigationEndpointData":{"url":"http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=https%3A//www.youtube.com/attribution_link%3Fa%3DEJTr_gotwJY%26u%3D%252Fwatch%253Fv%253DmyuWGmE6oBI%2526feature%253Dshare\u0026description=Gusttavo%20Lima%20-%20Thiago%20Brava%20e%20Amigos%20%28Transmiss%C3%A3o%20ao%20vivo%20pelo%20Facebook...\u0026is_video=true\u0026media=https%3A//i.ytimg.com/vi/myuWGmE6oBI/hqdefault.jpg"}},"trackingParams":"CIUBEKpMGAkiEwj6zdXiirnXAhVGcZAKHZp2CZ0o-B0yBXNoYXJlOgtFSlRyX2dvdHdKWUiSwOqJpsPllZsBaglQSU5URVJFU1RxQHXU4BQh6n54AQ==","serviceName":"PINTEREST"}}],"title":{"runs":[{"text":"Compartilhar este vídeo"}]},"copyUrlButtonText":{"runs":[{"text":"Copiar link"}]},"unregisteredAppClickTrackingParams":"EKpMMgVzaGFyZUiSwOqJpsPllZsBeAE=","trackingParams":"CH8Q4VAiEwj6zdXiirnXAhVGcZAKHZp2CZ0o-B0yBXNoYXJlSJLA6ommw-WVmwE=","startAt":{"startAtRenderer":{"startAtOptionLabel":{"runs":[{"text":"Começar em"}]}}},"actionButtons":[{"buttonRenderer":{"style":"STYLE_TEXT","size":"SIZE_DEFAULT","isDisabled":false,"text":{"simpleText":"Incorporar"},"serviceEndpoint":{"clickTrackingParams":"CIIBEPBbGAoiEwj6zdXiirnXAhVGcZAKHZp2CZ0o-B0=","signalServiceEndpoint":{"signal":"CLIENT_SIGNAL","actions":[{"signalAction":{"signal":"CLOSE_POPUP"}},{"signalAction":{"signal":"PAUSE_PLAYER"}},{"openPopupAction":{"popup":{"sharingEmbedRenderer":{"title":{"runs":[{"text":"Vídeo incorporado"}]},"videoId":"myuWGmE6oBI","showSuggestedVideosOptionLabel":{"runs":[{"text":"Mostrar vídeos sugeridos quando o vídeo terminar."}]},"showPlayerControlsOptionLabel":{"runs":[{"text":"Mostrar controles do player."}]},"showVideoTitleOptionLabel":{"runs":[{"text":"Mostrar título do vídeo e as ações do jogador."}]},"enablePrivacyModeOptionLabel":{"runs":[{"text":"Ativar o modo de privacidade aprimorada."}],"accessibility":{"accessibilityData":{"label":"Quando você ativa o modo de privacidade aprimorado, o YouTube não armazena informações sobre os visitantes do seu website, a menos que eles reproduzam o vídeo."}}},"legalInfo":{"runs":[{"text":"Ao incorporar vídeos do YouTube no seu site, você concorda com os "},{"text":"Termos de Serviço da API do YouTube","navigationEndpoint":{"clickTrackingParams":"CIIBEPBbGAoiEwj6zdXiirnXAhVGcZAKHZp2CZ0o-B0=","urlEndpoint":{"url":"https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/api-services-terms-of-service"},"webNavigationEndpointData":{"url":"https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/api-services-terms-of-service"}}}]},"startAt":
    {"startAtRenderer":{"startAtOptionLabel":{"runs":[{"text":"Começar em"}]}}},"embedOptionsLabel":{"runs":[{"text":"Opções de incorporação"}]},"apiReferenceLinkLabel":{"runs":[{"text":"Referência de API","navigationEndpoint":{"clickTrackingParams":"CIIBEPBbGAoiEwj6zdXiirnXAhVGcZAKHZp2CZ0o-B0=","urlEndpoint":{"url":"https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference"},"webNavigationEndpointData":{"url":"https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference"}}}]},"developerSampleLinkLabel":{"runs":[{"text":"Amostra do desenvolvedor","navigationEndpoint":{"clickTrackingParams":"CIIBEPBbGAoiEwj6zdXiirnXAhVGcZAKHZp2CZ0o-B0=","urlEndpoint":{"url":"https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo"},"webNavigationEndpointData":{"url":"https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo"}}}]},"actionButtons":[{"buttonRenderer":{"style":"STYLE_TEXT","size":"SIZE_DEFAULT","isDisabled":false,"text":{"simpleText":"Copiar"},"serviceEndpoint":{"clickTrackingParams":"CIMBEPBbGAAiEwj6zdXiirnXAhVGcZAKHZp2CZ0o-B0=","signalServiceEndpoint":{"signal":"CLIENT_SIGNAL","actions":[{"signalAction":{"signal":"COPY_SHARE_EMBED_URL"}},{"openPopupAction":{"popup":{"notificationActionRenderer":{"responseText":{"runs":[{"text":"Link copiado para a área de transferência"}]},"trackingParams":"CIQBELlqIhMI-s3V4oq51wIVRnGQCh2adgmdKPgd"}},"popupType":"TOAST"}}]}},"trackingParams":"CIMBEPBbGAAiEwj6zdXiirnXAhVGcZAKHZp2CZ0o-B0="}}]}},"popupType":"DIALOG"}}]}},"trackingParams":"CIIBEPBbGAoiEwj6zdXiirnXAhVGcZAKHZp2CZ0o-B0="}},{"buttonRenderer":{"style":"STYLE_TEXT","size":"SIZE_DEFAULT","isDisabled":false,"text":{"simpleText":"Copiar"},"serviceEndpoint":{"clickTrackingParams":"CIABEPBbGAsiEwj6zdXiirnXAhVGcZAKHZp2CZ0o-B0=","signalServiceEndpoint":{"signal":"CLIENT_SIGNAL","actions":[{"signalAction":{"signal":"COPY_SHARE_URL"}},{"openPopupAction":{"popup":{"notificationActionRenderer":{"responseText":{"runs":[{"text":"Link copiado para a área de transferência"}]},"trackingParams":"CIEBELlqIhMI-s3V4oq51wIVRnGQCh2adgmdKPgd"}},"popupType":"TOAST"}}]}},"trackingParams":"CIABEPBbGAsiEwj6zdXiirnXAhVGcZAKHZp2CZ0o-B0="}}]}}}},"accessibility":{"label":"Compartilhar"},"tooltip":"Compartilhar","trackingParams":"CH4Q8FsYBCITCPrN1eKKudcCFUZxkAodmnYJnSj4HQ==","accessibilityData":{"accessibilityData":{"label":"Compartilhar"}}}},{"buttonRenderer":{"style":"STYLE_DEFAULT","size":"SIZE_DEFAULT","isDisabled":false,"serviceEndpoint":{"clickTrackingParams":"CH0Q8FsYBSITCPrN1eKKudcCFUZxkAodmnYJnSj4HQ==","addToPlaylistServiceEndpoint":{"videoId":"myuWGmE6oBI"}},"icon":{"iconType":"PLAYLIST_ADD"},"accessibility":{"label":"Adicionar a"},"tooltip":"Adicionar a","trackingParams":"CH0Q8FsYBSITCPrN1eKKudcCFUZxkAodmnYJnSj4HQ==","accessibilityData":{"accessibilityData":{"label":"Adicionar a"}}}}],"accessibility":{"accessibilityData":{"label":"Mais ações"}}}},"trackingParams":"CHwQzKsBGAAiEwj6zdXiirnXAhVGcZAKHZp2CZ0o-B0=","sentimentBar":{"sentimentBarRenderer":{"percentIfIndifferent":95,"percentIfLiked":95,"percentIfDisliked":95,"likeStatus":"INDIFFERENT","tooltip":"512 / 23"}}}},{"videoSecondaryInfoRenderer":{"owner":{"videoOwnerRenderer":{"thumbnail":{"thumbnails":[{"url":"https://yt3.ggpht.com/-v4QOyDfaJBo/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/Ni7Sf5rFIc0/s88-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg","width":88,"height":88},{"url":"https://yt3.ggpht.com/-v4QOyDfaJBo/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/Ni7Sf5rFIc0/s176-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg","width":176,"height":176}]},"title":{"runs":[{"text":"Marco Gomes \u0026 Rodrigo","navigationEndpoint":{"clickTrackingParams":"CHsQ4TkiEwj6zdXiirnXAhVGcZAKHZp2CZ0o-B0=","browseEndpoint":{"browseId":"UCUlEH_VtYJf3LnT87qlD1ZA"}
</script>
```

Através da minha pagina usando php quero puxar a informação do "browseId", mas como faço isso, usando curl ou file_get_contents consigo?

Comment: Você recebe estes dados ou exibiu um código-fonte e colou aqui ? está muito complexo essa chegada de dados "criptografados"

Comment: Esse é um objeto JavaScript no HTML de um vídeo qualquer no YouTube. Consegui retirar um valor desse objeto de maneira bruta com JS localizando o index do valor que procuro e percorrendo a string até a próxima aspas `"`, no seu caso tem que começar a partir do final desta string: `"browseId":"`